# Switchin/reversing a string in a SharePoint list item

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, listitem

I have a question on whether it would be possible to switch/reverse the ordering of string values in a SharePoint list item in code behind to then display the result of the processed string.

So currently to illustrate this I have an "Employees" SharePoint list with the following columns:

- Title
- Position

Now the title column has the following values:

- Ted Baker
- Joe Pierce

I have a simple web part that displays the list item values, but for the "Title" field rather than displaying "Ted Baker", I want it to be displayed "Baker Ted" so essentially displaying the last string value first.

Is this possible to do and if so what would be the best way to do it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What would you want to display If it were `Ted Baker Jr.` or `Dr. Joe Pierce`?

Comment: The "Title" field will ever only hold name + surname (Ted Baker) so no actual titles like Jr. or Dr.

Answer (score 0):

```
string name = "Ted Baker";
string newname = String.Join(" ",name.Split(' ').Reverse());
```